# Visual Studio 2015 GitHub connection

Tags: github, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded a project from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015.  In 2013 I was using the Git Tools to connect to GitHub.  After upgrading to the project to 2015 I lost my connection to GitHub.  I have been making changes which have only been getting committed to the local git repository.  In Visual Studio 2015 how can I reconnect this local Git Repository to the GitHub one so I can push the commits up there? Unfortunately it was a few days before I noticed with lots of little commits so I want to try and keep the history if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can reconfigure your connection of github from visual studio itself.

1. Go To Team Explorer -> Settings
2. Go to Global settings to setup your git account. Enter email id of same account on which your git account is located. Enter your github account personal access token as a password. (Do not enter your git account password)
3. Click on update. Now to branch section. Change it if necessary. After checking in particular branch, you should be able to commit your code.
4. Pull your code first if there is any change in your online code. Solve merger conflicts if there are any and Then you will be able to push code.

I hope you get my point and able to solve your problem.